# Rails 6 form does not display errors - undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to display errors to the user inside of partial. I'm using below `simple_form`:

```
<%= simple_form_for :appropriateness_test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", label: "#{i+1}. #{q[:question]}", collection: q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a, i.to_s] }, as: :radio_buttons, wrapper_class: 'input simple-radio-buttons'%>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Which is rendered inside `new.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'appropriateness_test/shared/form', url: appropriateness_test_step_one_path, randomize_questions: @randomize_questions  %>
```

There is nothing special inside of the controller:

```
module AppropriatenessTest
  class BaseController < SignupBaseController
    before_action :randomize_questions, only: %i[new create]
    include AppropriatenessTest::ParserHelper

    def new
      @appropriateness_test_result = AppropriatenessTestResult.new
    end

    def create
      @appropriateness_test_result = current_user.appropriateness_test_results.new(
        answer: user_answers,
      )

      if @appropriateness_test_result.save
        redirect_to next_step_path
      else
        render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

# user_answers output 
{"0"=>{"id"=>"21", "answer"=>""},
 "1"=>{"id"=>"22", "answer"=>""},
 "2"=>{"id"=>"23", "answer"=>""},
 "3"=>{"id"=>"18", "answer"=>""},
 "4"=>{"id"=>"19", "answer"=>""},
 "5"=>{"id"=>"20", "answer"=>""}}
```

This is one of the steps in the registration process. But I cannot display the page with this form because the below error shows up:

```
undefined method errors for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):
1 <%= simple_form_for :appropriateness_test_results, url: url  do |f| %>
2 <%= f.error_notification %>
3  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
4
5  <% randomize_questions.each_with_index.map do |q, i| %>
6    <%= f.input "[#{i}][answer]", label: "#{i+1}. #{q[:question]}", collection: q[:answers].map.with_index { |a, i| [a, i.to_s] }, as: :radio_buttons, wrapper_class: 'input simple-radio-buttons'%>
```

When I remove the line responsible for displaying errors it works well but then, naturally, I am not able to display validation errors to the user. So the question is how to display errors and avoid this `undefined method` errors ?

Comment: So in other words, your question is: Why does `f.object == nil`? Did this code work with a previous version of rails and/or `simple_form` and/or ruby etc?

Comment: @TomLord That's right, why `f.object == nil`. I can't change Rails version (it's 6.1.3) if it comes to the `simple_form` (5.1.0 on board) I haven't tested it, but I don't think it makes any difference - I don't see any significant changes in simple_form CHANGELOG - https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Why not `simple_form_for @appropriateness_test_results`?

Comment: Shouldnt it be singular? @appropriateness_test_result?

Comment: @JoelBlum If I replace it by `@appropriateness_test_result` I'll be not able to build the answer form - `undefined method [0][answer]' for <AppropriatenessTestResult:0x00007ffb19318d20>` shows up. My goal is to have a hash of answers (just like `user_answers` from my question) from collection of radio buttons.

Comment: I would tweak the guard condition `if f.object.errors[:base].present?` to something like `if f.object && f.object.errors[:base].present?`

Comment: @HectorCorrea That doesn't change anything - errors will still not display because `f.object == nil`